# Reuse template with properties in Angular 7

Tags: angular, templates

I have this template that I used **everywhere** in my project :

```
<div class="col-xs-6 event" *ngFor="let event of events">
  <h1>{{ event.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ event.content }}</p>
</div>
```

I uses many properties : title, content, etc..

I have structured my project like this : `events-list.component.ts` that displays the list of the events and  `events-get.component.ts` that is the detail of an event. In the details of an event, I also display other events (such as the "you may also like" bloc).

I do not where and how to declare a **"template"** that i could use instead of duplicating this code.

Something like `<event-template></event-template>` but with the possibility of passing the properties.

Comment: you should create new component and declare @Input() variables title and content inside. You should read this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: You may find info on how to do that on https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Should I call the component `event.component.ts` ? The aim of this component would be only to hold the HTML template ?

Comment: I did it and I have this error : `Can't bind to 'event' since it isn't a known property of 'app-event'.` The code is : `<app-event class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let event of events" [event]="event"></app-event>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I succeed to achieve what I wanted.

I created a new component called **event**. I now have a `event.component.ts` :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event',
  templateUrl: './event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event.component.css']
})
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() event: Event;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I set the template of this component as the one that I want to reuse everywhere.

Then, in my `events-list.component.ts`, I can use :

```
<app-event class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let event of events" [event]="event"></app-event>
```

It is perfect !